# Is it possible to set a default path in PathField?

Tags: aem

A Granite/Coral component PathField (`granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/pathfield`) provides a dialog box to select a path. Is it possible to set a default path to start from? I mean, something that can be changed by the user, not `rootPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the `value` property? It's what the widget sets when you click through the content tree and select a page/resource. If you set this yourself in the dialog definition, the dialog should load with your path pre-set and allow the user to change it if necessary.